# Can I replace my Asus Windows 10 with Debian and run the Windows in a virtual machine?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, windows-10

I have an Asus laptop with Windows 10 on it and I want to put Debian on it.
Is it possible to save my copy of Windows 10 (it came with the laptop) and make it a virtual machine on the same machine just with Debian installed as the host or am I doomed to pick 1 or the other (or dual boot)?

Answer (score 1):

If your Windows 10 license came with the laptop then it is tied to the motherboard in it's UEFI and cannot be used by a virtual machine.

A virtual machine is separate from the host machine and purposely isolated for many reasons including security. Windows will not detect the license and demand for a license key during installation on the virtual machine. Licenses cannot be extracted from UEFI, it was designed that way.

Your scenario requires you to have a separate license of Windows 10 for the virtual machine.

Comment: If you are a student in a participating college or university, you will have access to Dreamspark which offers a free Windows 10 license among many other Microsoft software.

Comment: "Your scenario requires you to have a separate license of Windows 10 for the virtual machine." - This is 100% false.  With Windows 10 came slightly different licensing with virtual machines.  Provide the Virtual Machine is ran on the same hard, one can run the installation,   within a virtual machine.  This has to do with the fact the hardware hash would be identical.